# How to draw Vector rounded rectangle in Graphics32 library? Is this possible?

Tags: delphi, graphics32

How to draw vector [rounded rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxwEp.png) in Graphics32 library? Is this possible?

Not a raster, should be vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphics32 is a raster image library. Its primary image type is `TBitmap32` which is a raster image. It does not have vector image capabilities.

Comment: What is a different vector image drawing library?

Comment: Well, I don't know. You could search online. What are you looking for especially? Google+ delphi devs group would be a better place to ask.

Comment: With the latest code in the SVN it does contain vector graphic capacibilities. And even before it did, but it was far more difficult to handle as the antialiasing was solved by oversampling.
This said Graphics32 is still only a raster image library and as such the vector graphics need to be rendered to a raster image on every change (like resizing).

Comment: @CW Perhaps you might have updated the answer to reflect these changes rather than down voting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a web search, you will find a unit called G32_Interface, with routines for drawing true type fonts, bezier curves, ellipse and rotated ellipse, rounded polygons and splines. Its author is Roman Gudchenko.

Also check this link [draw antialiased rounded rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048204/delphi-graphics32-draw-antialiased-rounded-rectangle?rq=1)

Comment: Which are rasterized onto a `TBitmap32` raster image

Comment: sure, the final layer to display a vector object is a raster image. I think GR32 library is right for drawing vector objects.

Answer (score 1):

The latest code in the trunk (SVN) contains the VPR vector graphics engine. It's still somehow in a beta state, but available since several years now. With this you can draw a rounded rectangle quite easily:

```
uses
  GR32, GR32_Polygons, GR32_VectorUtils;

[...]
var
  Points: TArrayOfFloatPoint;
begin
  Points := RoundRect(Rect(RectLeft, RectTop, RectRight, RectBottom), Radius);
  PolyPolygonFS(MyBitmap32, Points, Color32);
end;
```

where RectLeft, RectTop, Radius, Color32 has to be specified by the user.